# Binding List to HTML

Tags: nancy

does anyone know how to bind a list item to html in Nancy?

Here's the code I have:

```
Get["/topics"] = parameters 
    =>
      {
         var model = new TopicsModel();
         model.Load(); // it populates some rows of type TopicModel
         return Negotiate.WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK)
           .WithModel(model)
           .WithView("topics");
     };
```

My TopicsModel:

```
public class TopicsModel
{
    public void Load() { Models = ...}
    public List<TopicModel> Models { get; set; }
}
```

and the TopicModel:

```
public class TopicModel
{
    public string TopicName { get; set; }
    public string TopicImageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried the below in my HTML but none of them seem to be working.

```
<div class="row">
    <h3>TopicName[0]</h3>
    <h3>@Model.Models[0].TopicName</h3>
    <h3>Models[0].TopicName</h3>
 </div>
```

The results for these three are (in order):

> TopicName[0]
>
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[...Models.TopicModel][0].TopicName
>
> Models[0].TopicName

I have also tried other things but none have worked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,

Update: Apparently it's not possible. I ended up using the Razor engine which works for my use-case.

Comment: Are you using Razor or Super Simple View Engine?

Comment: Simple View Engine. I decided to use Razor because of this and everything works on Razor however I will keep the question open in case anyone knows the answer for SVE.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/The-Super-Simple-View-Engine#iterators

```
@ForEach.Models
<div class="row">
    <h3>@Current.TopicName</h3>
</div>
@EndEach
```

Be aware that Simple Simple View Engine does not support nested loops (currently)

Comment: Thank you Phill. I'd seen this but unfortunately my usage is a bit different. I would like to directly index into the list instead of iterating over it, i.e. get Topic[2].TopicName for example. I could get the iteration working but couldn't get the indexing working. I don't have this problem with the Razor engine though.

Comment: That's not possible sorry.